# How do I access a package after git cloning it into my project?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I git cloned the following package into my existing project and have followed the instructions for setup: https://github.com/ensdomains/reverse-records

Now how do I access this package in my react native js files, so I can use the `ReverseRecords` function?

Answer (score 0):

You mean, that you want to use a local directory that contains the reverse-records package ?

If so in the package.json just add the relative path, from [npm docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/configuring-npm/package-json#local-paths) :

```
{
  "name": "baz",
  "dependencies": {
    "@ensdomains/reverse-records": "file:../foo/reverse-records"
  }
}
```

Or shorter but it's not in [npm docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/configuring-npm/package-json#local-paths) you can get rid of 'file:' :

```
{
      "name": "baz",
      "dependencies": {
        "@ensdomains/reverse-records": "../foo/reverse-records"
      }
}
```